# How to Get Specific Object Using SelectById(object_id) in SpringBoot-MyBatis-MySQL?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, mybatis, ibatis

I managed to "get all objects" by creating a SELECT statement in SpringBoot-MyBatis backend like:

*AppRestController.java*

```
//get full list of actors 
@GetMapping("/actors")
public List<Actor> selectAllActors(){
        return actorMapper.selectAllActors();
}
```

When you type "localhost:9090/actors" in the browser, it will return all actor objects from my MySQL DB. That's good. Now I want to take its complexity up a notch.

I want to fetch a single object by it's actor_id like:

```
//get specific actor by actor_id. this is where im stuck
@GetMapping("/actors/id")
public Actor selectActorById(int id){
     return actorMapper.selectActorById(id);
}
```

Notice my **@GetMapping**. What I want to do is when I type something like
"**localhost:9090/actors/1**" in the browser, it will return actor object from database with id = 1, and so forth.

Here are the relevant files.

*ActorMapper.xml*

```
<mapper namespace="com.helios.mybatissakila.mappers.ActorMapper">

    <resultMap id="ActorResultMap" type="Actor">
        <id column="actor_id" property="actor_id" jdbcType="INTEGER"/>
        <result column="first_name" property="first_name" />
        <result column="last_name" property="last_name" />
        <result column="last_update" property="last_update" />
    </resultMap>

<select id="selectAllActors" resultMap="ActorResultMap">
        select * from actor
</select>

<select id="selectActorById" resultMap="ActorResultMap">
        select * from actor where actor_id = #{actor_id}
</select>

</mapper>
```

*ActorMapper.java*

```
@Mapper
public interface ActorMapper {
    //this is now working
    List <Actor> selectAllActors();
    //this is where im stuck
    Actor selectActorById(int id);
}
```

Thanks for your help.
**Update**:

so I did change

```
@GetMapping("/actors/id")
public Actor selectActorById(int id){
     return actorMapper.selectActorById(id);
}
```

to

```
@GetMapping("/actors/{id}")
public Actor selectActorById(Integer id){
     return actorMapper.selectActorById(id);
}
```

Apparently, no errors, but Im getting a blank screen. Why? There is a data from my MySQL DB whose actor_id is equal to 1.

[image]

Comment: Please do not use [solved] title hacks here - we don't use them on Stack Overflow. If you have answer material, it need to go in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your get mapping as follow:

```
@GetMapping("/actors/{id}")
public Actor selectActorById(@PathVariable(name="id") int id){
     return actorMapper.selectActorById(id);
}
```

Your `{id}` will be path variable which will be mapped to `id` parameter of method

Comment: oh, dont forget about the @PathVariable, this is nice! :)

Comment: @PathVariable is the important part here

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

You must include the @PathVariable annotation as mentioned by @Abhijeet:

[image]

Comment: I dont think this is necessary. You can see  I already accepted @Abhijeet's answer and even included it in my original post.

Comment: @noogui: yes, and it's the including it in your original post that is the problem. `:-)` Questions and answers are best kept separate here, not least for the Data API, where question and answer posts are treated as separately requestable entities. (If you want, you can repost this answer yourself, and I'll delete the CW version).

Comment: (However, if you wish, we can just delete this answer - my purpose was to take it out of the question).

Answer (score 0):

```
    @GetMapping("/actors")
    public Actor selectActorById(@RequestParam("id") int id){
        return actorMapper.selectActorById(id);//use "localhost:9090/actors?id=1" to Visit

    }
```